# How to get a while loop to wait for user input?

Tags: linux, bash

In the first loop it waits for the user to type something, where in the second loop it doesn't.

```
for f in *; do
  echo $f
  IFS= read -r opt
done

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*" | while read f; do
  echo $f
  IFS= read -r opt
done
```

**Question**

How can I get the while loop to wait for the user input just like the for-loop does?

Comment: Your last `read` also reads from stdin (stdout of find).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the loop happens in a pipeline, so the standard input is redirected to the output of the previous pipeline command. You can use `exec` to redirect normal standard input to a different file descriptor and read user input from there:

```
exec 3<&0
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*" | while read f; do
  echo $f
  IFS= read -r -u3 opt
  echo $opt
done
exec 3<&-  # Close fd3
```

Comment: Overall, this is an excellent approach, but depending on the situation it is also often desirable to do `read < /dev/tty`.  If the intent is to wait for 'the user to type something', reading from /dev/tty is probably appropriate.